# chrome.filesystem track directory to changes

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm developing Chrome App.
Is it possible to track Chosen Entry (and all child folders/files) for changes using chrome.filesystem?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/FileSystem). There's no built-in method for tracking changes. Apparently, you'll have to implement it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some [discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=261491) on the Chromium issue tracker for implementing an Entry Watcher API. However, there hasn't been much traction on it. The [chrome.fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) doesn't provide any options for watching/tracking changes to files and folders - only the [chrome.fileSystemProvider](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider#event-onAddWatcherRequested) API for Chrome OS only does that.

The FileSystem API is really [not well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem) these days, so it may be best to avoid it. You may have better luck with the [Chrome Sync FileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage#sync-filesystem) API though, using the `onFileStatusChanged` event for tracking the changes.

There is currently development on introducing [Observers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=609934) to IndexedDB which would be the preferred option I suspect.

Comment: chrome.fileSystem is not the same as the web filesystem api. And IDB observers would be useless because it does not act on user files.